# What is the expectation of a normal random variable divided by uniform random variable?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, uniform-distribution

I have two random variables: $x = N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $y =U[0, b]$.  I need to compute $E(x/(1+y))$.  How does one go about doing this?  They are independent so the joint pdf is just the product of the two pdfs but can the integral be computed in closed form or is this something that should just be done numerically?

Comment: Is this homework? Hint: Try to reason by symmetry…

Comment: 1. No this is not homework.
2. That's true, I should have been more specific: The equation in my model is actually $\frac{1}{1+y}$ so it does not diverge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your description (and comments) you're trying to calculate $E \left( \frac{X}{1+Y} \right)$ where $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim {\rm Uniform}(0,b)$. By independence,

$$E \left( \frac{X}{1+Y} \right) = E(X) \cdot E \left( \frac{1}{1+Y} \right)$$

We know $E(X) = 0$, therefore 
$$E \left( \frac{X}{1+Y} \right) = 0$$

as long as $ E \left( \frac{1}{1+Y} \right) $ is finite. We know  that $\frac{1}{1+Y}$ is bounded within $\left(\frac{1}{1+b},1 \right)$ with probability 1, therefore its mean also is.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's not homework, then the expectation is zero by symmetry.  How could there be an argument suggesting the answer is $k>0$ without a similar argument suggesting $-k$?

Comment: I presume you mean the symmetry under $x \to -x$. But you do need to establish that the expectation even exists before you can apply that ... :-).

Comment: @whuber: Yes, you're right.  I initially wrote it up as the expectation is either zero or doesn't exist, but then he edited his question and it was clear that it did exist.  Macro has a nice explicit answer.

Comment: The problem would have been more interesting if X had a mean different from 0.  Then you would have to calculate E(1/(1+y))